# Searching for indexes of multiple subtrings in multiple files

Tags: python, string, algorithm, search

I've got two dataframes which are as follows:

```
df1 : contains one variable ['search_term'] and 100000 rows
```

These are words/phrases I want to search for in my files

```
df2: contains parsed file contents in a column called file_text
```

There are 20000 rows in this dataframe and two columns ['file_name', 'file_text']

What I need is the index of each appearance of a search term in the file_text.

I cannot figure out an efficient way to perform this search.

I am using the str.find() function along with groupby but it's taking around 0.25s per file_text-search term (which becomes really long with 20k files*100k search terms)

Any ideas on ways to do this in a fast and efficient way would be lifesavers!

Comment: Shorten your problem to a representative example with inputs and expected output. Basically, look at how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you have working code and you want improve it, you'll have better chance here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what do you mean by `dataframe`? I've never heard of such thing.

Comment: If you are looking for exact matches, consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Comment: The `re` engine already does something very similar to aho-corasick. In fact, we did try that, and it didn't outperform `re.finditer`.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having to do something similar in one of our projects. We had a very large set of keywords and we wanted to search for them in a large string and find all occurrences of those keywords. Let's call the string we want to search in `content`. After some bench-marking, the solution I adopted was a two pass method: first check to see if a keyword exists in the `content` using the highly optimized `in` operator, and then use regular expressions to find all occurrences of it.

```
import re

keywords = [...list of your keywords ...]
found_keywords = []

for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in content:
        found_keywords.append(keyword)

for keyword in found_keywords:
    for match in re.finditer(keyword, content):
        print(match.start())
```